# I need to access an item inside an array inside an array how to go about it (react & javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Patient array inside of every patient there is a relatives array inside is an id and a relationship I want to show the relationship based on the id
here is an image for the data
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
 props.data.slice(0, props.n).map((item) => {
                    return (
                            <Grid item xl={4} md={4} xs={4}>
                                <Link to={`/patient/${item.id}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: theme.palette.text.primary }}>
                                    <Card boxShadow={3} key={item.id} style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.card }}>
                                        <CardImg src={item.imgUri} alt={item.name} onError={addDefaultSrc} />
                                        //here I want to show the relationship
                                    </Card>
                                </Link>
                            </Grid>
   )
}
```

now to explain it more I have the for every patient a page and there are relative patient section the i render every paitent passed on the rletiveid now i already have the patient id stored now i wont to go throe all the relatives array and find where is == the patient id that i stored and return the relationshop the rletiveid should be unique it means every patient should return one relationshop

Comment: Could you post a sample json object?

Comment: I edited the question you can  one have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to map again on your relatives.

```
 props.data.slice(0, props.n).map((item) => {
     return (
         <Grid item xl={4} md={4} xs={4}>
              <Link to={`/patient/${item.id}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: theme.palette.text.primary }}>
                 <Card boxShadow={3} key={item.id} style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.card }}>
                   <CardImg src={item.imgUri} alt={item.name} onError={addDefaultSrc} />
                      {item.relatives.map(relative => (<span key={relative.relativeId}>{relative.relationship}</span>))}
                 </Card>
              </Link>
         </Grid>
   )
}
```

Comment: it work but it show all the data i have a patient id and i want it to show when relative id == patient id how can i do that?

Comment: Based on your Json object. You want to compare this id "id: "s9xiyj06ey5hefrjss6d"" with the "relativeId: "k89alqkewo1j072mo3eb"" and only render when they are equal, that's it?

Comment: no don't look at it like that imagine every patient have multiple relative now I am at the patient page and have his id now I want to look at this json object and search if this object (patient) = the id of the patient i am looking at if you still don't get it i will but an image of what i am doing

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Try to edit with an image of the relative you're trying to filter.

Comment: I put an image do you see that patient he have 2 relative i want to show there relationship for this patient

Comment: Imagine i want to show the relationship  for this id "k89alqkewo1j072mo3eb" how can i do it

Comment: If you only want to show some results, you can filter before you map {item.relatives
            .filter((relative) => relative.relativeId === 'k89alqkewo1j072mo3eb')
            .map((relative) => (
              <span key={relative.relativeId}>{relative.relashionship}</span>
            ))}

Comment: But use the id you want to compare instead of "k89alqkewo1j072mo3eb"